# Hibernate: Is it okay to not bind SessionFactory to a JNDI name?

Tags: hibernate, jndi, sessionfactory

There is a way to set the JNDI name of a SessionFactory in the hibernate.cfg.xml file. However, if I'm not explicitly using JNDI lookup to get my SessionFactory at all in my web app, is it okay to NOT give it a JNDI name?

The reason I ask is that if I didn't set up my JNDI name, my JUnit tests will run fine. But if I do set it up by only specifying 'name' in the sessionfactory tag in hibernate.cfg.xml, it will first say:

```
WARN  [WebApp:SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance] Could not bind factory to JNDI
```

and the throw an exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an appletparameter, or in an application resource file:
```

So my get around is to remove the JNDI name from my hibernate.cfg.xml, but don't know if that will cause other problems or not?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it would be ok most of the times, but you could also consider using a different hibernate.cfg.xm for your JUnit tests.

Comment: How do you go about doing this exactly? How do you specify in Java to use a different mapping file for Unit tests?

Comment: You can either change the classpath to include one config file or the other, or you can build the SessionFactory in Java with a specific configuration file with Configuration.configure("hibernate-test.cfg.xml").

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the attribute name, with value = "sessionFactory "in configuration file
it will be ok.